# JavaFX Pagination, adding << and >>> options

Tags: javafx, pagination

I am doing a data displaying app and I need to add a option to my pagination which can be used to go back to the first page (index) or go to the last one.

I already tried adding buttons to my UI but it did not work because I could not obtain the last index.

```
@FXML
void goToLastIndex(ActionEvent event) {
    int lastIndex = pagination.getPageCount();
    pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(lastIndex);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I could not obtain the last index"? In other words, what value are you getting for `lastIndex`? Since the `currentPageIndex` is zero-based, you probably need `pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(lastIndex-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the pageCountProperty of the pagination.

```
/**
* Returns the number of pages.
*/
public final int getPageCount() { return pageCount.get(); }

/**
 * The number of pages for this pagination control.  This
 * value must be greater than or equal to 1. {@link #INDETERMINATE}
 * should be used as the page count if the total number of pages is unknown.
 *
 * The default is an {@link #INDETERMINATE} number of pages.
 */
public final IntegerProperty pageCountProperty() { return pageCount; }
```

Comment: I still get a index that is way too big. It returns 2147483647 and the last index should be 961.

Comment: 2147483647 is the size of an Integer.MAX_VALUE 0x7fffffff. Did you initialize your control properly?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html#pageCountProperty) the default value of `pageCount` is `Pagination.INDETERMINATE`, which is (more or less arbitrarily) equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If your pagination has a fixed number of pages (if not, it doesn't really make sense to have a "last page"), then you should initialize it by calling the [constructor taking a page count value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html#Pagination-int-), or call `setPageCount(...)` and specify the number of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, all I needed to do was to create a variable that keeps the number of page and use it with a setOnAction.

```
int numberOfPage = (nbOfDataForCurrentType / ROW_PER_PAGE + 1);
        pagination = new Pagination(numberOfPage, 0);
        pagination.setPageFactory(param -> populateTableView(param));
        getChildren().add(pagination);

        if (numberOfPage > 1) {
            btnEnd.onActionProperty().set(event -> pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(numberOfPage));
            btnBegin.setOnAction(event -> pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(0));

            getChildren().add(btnBegin);
            getChildren().add(btnEnd);
        }

    });
```