# How to extend JavaFX Pagination navigation to display additional controls?

Tags: java, layout, pagination, javafx-8

I would like to use Pagination to show a table page wise. This works in principle but I would like to add additional controls that are in the same line as the default pagination navigation:

- button for going to first page ("<<")
- text field for jumping to specified page index
- button for going to last page (">>")
- text field for number of entries per page
- search text field for jumping to a page that contains the row entry with a given ID.

I am able to customize the page above the pagination control with the method setPageFactory() but I am not able to customize the navigation control itself. How to do that? If I add my additional controls above or below the default navigation I waste some space:

[image]

Related article:
[JavaFX Pagination, adding << and >>> options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870251/javafx-pagination-adding-and-options)

Filed an [enhancement request](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8132131)

Comment: custom navigation is not supported - it is a package private class (NavigationControl) that's hard-coded and hard-wired into the PaginationSkin. Your only option (that I can see) is to roll your own skin (mostly c&p) with a custom navigation control (never tried, though)

Comment: I haven't checked, but if this cannot be changed with public API you might want to file an enhancement request: http://bugs.java.com/

Comment: I filed an enhancement request: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8132131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom navigation controls are not supported. While waiting for [the enhancement request](http://%20bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8132131) to be fixed, we could apply a hack (if QA guidelines allow) as outlined below. It's a hack because everything related to the navigation control is package private in PaginationSkin which itself is not (yet) public api.

The basic idea is to insert additional nodes into core navigation control, which obviously implies relying on implementation details (dont, dont, dont :-). We do so on-the-fly at instantiation and whenever the next button is inserted again - core clears out all its children quite often during layout and state changes on the pagination. This involves:

- lookup the pane that contains the buttons, it's selector is control-box
- keep a reference to its last child, which is the next button
- add a listener to the pane's children to be able to insert custom controls

Code example for a custom skin, here simply two button for first/last:

```
public static class CustomPaginationSkin extends PaginationSkin {

    private HBox controlBox;
    private Button prev;
    private Button next;
    private Button first;
    private Button last;

    private void patchNavigation() {
        Pagination pagination = getSkinnable();
        Node control = pagination.lookup(".control-box");
        if (!(control instanceof HBox))
            return;
        controlBox = (HBox) control;
        prev = (Button) controlBox.getChildren().get(0);
        next = (Button) controlBox.getChildren().get(controlBox.getChildren().size() - 1);

        first = new Button("A");
        first.setOnAction(e -> {
            pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(0);
        });
        first.disableProperty().bind(
                pagination.currentPageIndexProperty().isEqualTo(0));

        last = new Button("Z");
        last.setOnAction(e -> {
            pagination.setCurrentPageIndex(pagination.getPageCount());
        });
        last.disableProperty().bind(
                pagination.currentPageIndexProperty().isEqualTo(
                        pagination.getPageCount() - 1));

        ListChangeListener childrenListener = c -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                // implementation detail: when nextButton is added, the setup is complete
                if (c.wasAdded() && !c.wasRemoved() // real addition
                        && c.getAddedSize() == 1 // single addition
                        && c.getAddedSubList().get(0) == next) { 
                    addCustomNodes();
                }
            }
        };
        controlBox.getChildren().addListener(childrenListener);
        addCustomNodes();
    }

    protected void addCustomNodes() {
        // guarding against duplicate child exception 
        // (some weird internals that I don't fully understand...)
        if (first.getParent() == controlBox) return;
        controlBox.getChildren().add(0, first);
        controlBox.getChildren().add(last);
    }

    /**
     * @param pagination
     */
    public CustomPaginationSkin(Pagination pagination) {
        super(pagination);
        patchNavigation();
    }

}
```